# Xamarin.Essentials Unable to select images in "File Picker" on iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, filepicker, xamarin.essentials

When I try to select an image using the "File Picker" in Xamarin.Essentials, I can't select it only in the iOS simulator.

[image]

Xamarin.Essentials: File Picker
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios

```cs
var options = new PickOptions
{
  PickerTitle = "Please select files",
  FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Images,
};

IEnumerable<FileResult> results = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(options);
```

`FilePickerFileType.Jpeg` setting did not work for me. In addition, I could not select a PDF file with `FilePickerFileType.Pdf` settings.

However, when I launched the Android simulator, I was able to select the image successfully; only the iOS simulator was unable to select it.

Since `PickerTitle` is also not reflected, it seems that `options` itself is not enabled.

Also, even if I modified the `customFileType` area as pointed out in the answer below, it still did not allow me to select files.

```cs
var customFileType =
  new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
  {
      {DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { "com.adobe.pdf" , "public.jpeg" } },
  });

var options = new PickOptions
  {
      PickerTitle = "Please select files",
      //FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Images,
      FileTypes = customFileType,
  };

IEnumerable<FileResult> results = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(options);
```

Do I need to set anything else?

- Apple M1(macOS Monterey)
- Visual Studio for Mac 8.10.17
- Xamarin.Essentials 1.7.0
- Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2291

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your FileTypes property is set to FilePickerFileType.Images, pdf files are not allowed to select. So when setting FileTypes, you need to add it.

Here is the background code:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<FileResult> results =  PickAndShow();
}
async Task<FileResult> PickAndShow()
{
    var customFileType =
        new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            {DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { "com.adobe.pdf" , "public.image" } },
        });
    try
    {
        var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
        {
            PickerTitle = "Please select files",
            FileTypes = customFileType,  
        }) ;
        if (result != null)
        {
            Text = $"File Name: {result.FileName}";
            if (result.FileName.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                result.FileName.EndsWith("png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
                Image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // The user canceled or something went wrong
    }
    return null;
}
```

The main difference is that I create a customFileType and use it when setting FileTypes.

Comment: I created a `customFileType` as advised and invoked the File Picker, but I still could not select the image file. PDF files cannot be selected as well. I have added this to the question above. Is there anything else you can think of?

Comment: I copied your updated code completely, and the result can still be selected as pdf. It is recommended that you test it with a real machine.

Comment: It worked on the real machine!　So it looks like there is a problem with the simulator in my environment. Thank you very much.